# Fast Alternative to SciPy.interpolate.griddata()

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, linear-algebra

I need to apply interpolate.griddata to time series data; once per time step for a very long time series.  The code I'm trying to speed up is below.  p >> n, m.

I could trade off accuracy for performance to speed up this computation.  I would consider projecting this non-grid data onto a fine grid (with sparce entries), then interpolate the missing values, if it means I can leverage numpy matrix operations.

If the preferred approach is not possible, I could split p time steps into into many parallel processes.

Note that x and y are fixed for each time step.  If I could extract the coefficients for filling in my grid for one time step, I could apply those same coefficients for all time steps.  This should drastically simplify and speed up the computation however I don't know enough about the interpolation method being applied (CloughTocher2DInterpolator).

```
pressures = np.zeros((n, m, p))
for t in range(p):
    pressures[:, :, t] = interpolate.griddata((x, y), p[t], (xx, yy))
```

Note: This is being deployed as an Azure Function.  The loops are independent and can run in parallel, however I'm unfamiliar with the parallel processing capabilities of Azure functions.

Comment: It depends on the details of your data, but the `multiprocessing` module is often a good approach for embarrassingly parallel work like this.

Comment: Yes the loop can be run in parallel.  I was hoping to avoid the for loop however so the implementation can be handled by numpy with optimized c code.

Comment: There are a few tools for running functions across a dimension of an array, eg., [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html?highlight=apply_along_axis#numpy.apply_along_axis), but they usually boil down to a Python loop over that axis in any case, or only work on 1D arrays, or have other drawbacks. Parallelizing with `multiprocessing` is simple enough that I'd really recommend experimenting to see if it satisfies your performance requirements.

Comment: I implemented it with multiprocessing and ran it locally.  It runs slower with multiprocessing.  There is too much overhead to start a new process for each step t.